# Problems creating thumbnail in PHP form

Tags: php, gd

I'm having difficulty getting this part of my script to create a thumbnail, I have 0777 on the thumbnails folder but code won't create a thumbnail, any suggestions ?

```
if (isset($_FILES['user_photo']) && !empty($_FILES['user_photo']['name'])) {

$upload_dir ="images";
$thum_dir= "thumbnails";
$img =   $_FILES["user_photo"]["name"];  
//$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["user_photo"]["name"]);
//$file_name = $temp[0].'_'.time();
//$file_ext = $temp[1];
//$img = $file_name . '.' . $file_ext;



$orgfile = $_FILES["user_photo"]["tmp_name"];
list($width,$height)= getimagesize($orgfile);
$newfile = imagecreatefromjpeg($orgfile);
$newwidth = "150";
$newheight = "100";
$thum = $_FILES["user_photo"]["name"];

$truecolor = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresampled($truecolor, $newfile, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($truecolor,$thum,100);

copy($_FILES['user_photo']['tmp_name'], "$upload_dir/$img");
copy($_FILES['user_photo']['name'], "$thum_dir/$thum");
}
```

Comment: As you are uploading user images to a directory I highly recommend using MYSQL so you can record image names and unlink (delete) old images if the user updates their image. This will help save space on your server.

Answer (score 1):

For a manageable image upload system I highly recommend using MYSQL to help save space on your server and make selecting and displaying images easier.

To do this you need to create a MYSQL table with an id (primary, auto incrementing key) and then 3 additional columns for user, image and thumb, set them to null Yes and Collation to utf8_general_ci.

Now create your user credentials for accessing the database and table. I'm not going to go into that part.

Lastly create 2 folders for images. In this example the 2 folders are called "images" and "thumbs". Permissions for both folders should be set at 755.

```
 <?php
 if (isset($_FILES['user_photo'])) {

 // Your MYSQL connection file
 require_once ('db.php');

 // Thumbnail maker function to be called later - do not alter this
 function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width) {
 $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
 $width = imagesx($source_image);
 $height = imagesy($source_image);
 $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));
 $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);
 imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);
 imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);
 }

 // File settings
 $username = "user01"; // Example: you need some info to identify the user
 $target_dir = "/images/"; // Folder for main images
 $extension = array("jpeg","jpg","png"); // images only - add more extensions as required
 $limit = 5242880; // max 5mb - change this if required
 $upload = true; // Initially set to true unless checks fail!
 $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["user_photo"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // Get file extension
 $time = preg_replace('/(0)\.(\d+) (\d+)/', '$3$1$2', microtime()); // Unique prefix file name based on time
 $dot = "."; // Just a dot
 $new_filename = $time . $dot . $ext; // Full file name

 // Delete image files & MYSQL record if already uploaded
 $check = mysqli_query($con, "select image from images where user='$username'");
 if (mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0) {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check)) {
 $imageold = $row['image'];
 unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/$imageold"); // Delete old image main file
 unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/thumbs/$imageold"); // Delete old image thumb file
 $delete = mysqli_prepare($con, "delete from images where user=?");
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($delete, "s", $username);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($delete);
 }
 }

 // Check file size
 if ($_FILES["user_photo"]["size"] > $limit) {$upload = false;}

 // Check file extension
 if (in_array($ext, $extension) == false) {$upload = false;}

 // Upload file if checks ok + insert image record to MYSQL table
 if ($upload == true) {
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_photo']['tmp_name'], $target_dir . $new_filename);
 $insert = mysqli_prepare($con, "insert into images (user,image) values (?,?)");
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insert, "ss", $username, $new_filename);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($insert);
 }

 // If main image inserted, create thumb
 if ($insert) {
 echo "FILE UPLOADED";
 $select = mysqli_query($con, "select image from images where user='$username'");
 if (mysqli_num_rows($select) == 1) {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
 $imagename = $row['image'];
 $src = "/images/$imagename";
 $dest = "/thumbs/$imagename";
 $desired_width = "250"; // This will create a square thumb at 250px, alter size if required
 make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width); // Create thumb
 // Now update existing user record to include thumb
 $update = mysqli_prepare($con, "update images set thumb=? where user=?");
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update, "ss", $imagename, $username);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($update);
 }
 }
 }

 }
 ?>
```